# Pandas apply function read in list horizontally as an input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

Is there a way for the apply function to read in a list of values horizontally row-wise from the 3 columns ['A','B','C'] into a list 'x' as well as number from 'Val' as 'y' to the apply function to create a new column 'Result'?

I've presented the column f as more simplistic, I just need to know how to read a list/series into the function f

```
import pandas as pd
cols=['Name','A','B','C','Type','Val']
data = [['Front',1,2,3,'Up',11],
        ['Front',4,5,6,'Dw',22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

def f(x,y):
    return sum(x)*y
```

### not sure this is correct

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row[['A','B','C']],row['Val'],axis=1))
```

Initial Data:

```
    Name    A   B   C   Type    Val
0   Front   1   2   3   Up      11
1   Front   4   5   6   Dw      22
```

Desired Result:

```
    Name    A   B   C   Type    Val  Result
0   Front   1   2   3   Up      11   66
1   Front   4   5   6   Dw      22   330
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly vectorize this!

```py
df["Result"] = (df["A"] + df["B"] + df["C"]) * df["Val"]
```

Comment: But `f()` could presumably be redefined.

Comment: thanks for input but the function f presented is simpler than what I am trying to do, need the list/series input into the function f somehow

Comment: ah, alas, this was before the edit .. still, if you _can_ vectorize instead of doing a row-wise native Python function, it'll be much faster!

Answer (score 3):

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Name', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Type', 'Val']
data = [['Front', 1, 2, 3, 'Up', 11],
        ['Front', 4, 5, 6, 'Dw', 22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

def f(x, y):
    return sum(x) * y

df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row[['A', 'B', 'C']].values.tolist(), row['Val']), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Result:

```
Name  A  B  C Type  Val  Result
0  Front  1  2  3   Up   11      66
1  Front  4  5  6   Dw   22     330
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row[['A', 'B', 'C']], row['Val']), axis=1)
```

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['Name', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'Type', 'Val']
data = [['Front', 1, 2, 3, 'Up', 11],
        ['Front', 4, 5, 6, 'Dw', 22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

def f(x, y):
    return sum(x) * y

df['Result'] = df.apply(lambda row: f(row[['A', 'B', 'C']], row['Val']), axis=1)

print(df)
```